# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.chocolate.ModelChatlist

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

am trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime database and want to display them on the screen in the TextView but facing error.

The error displayed int the logcat is:
[image]

The code of ChatListFragment class is given below:

```
public class ChatListFragment extends Fragment {

  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  List<ModelChatlist> chatlistList;
  List<ModelUser> userList;
  DatabaseReference reference;
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  AdapterChatlist adapterChatlist;

  public ChatListFragment(){
      //required empty
  }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false);

      firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

      recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

      chatlistList = new ArrayList<>();

      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(currentUser.getUid());
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              chatlistList.clear();
              for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  ModelChatlist chatlist = ds.getValue(ModelChatlist.class);
                  chatlistList.add(chatlist);
              }
              loadChats();
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });

        return view;
    }

    private void loadChats() {
      userList = new ArrayList<>();
      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              userList.clear();
              for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  ModelUser user = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);
                  for (ModelChatlist chatlist: chatlistList){
                      if (user.getUid() != null && user.getUid().equals(chatlist.getId())) {
                          userList.add(user);
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  adapterChatlist = new AdapterChatlist(getContext(), userList);
                  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChatlist);
                  for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++ ) {
                      lastMessage(userList.get(i).getUid());
                  }
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
    }

    private void lastMessage(String userId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String theLastMessage = "default";
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelChat chat = ds.getValue(ModelChat.class);
                    if (chat==null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String sender = chat.getSender();
                    String receiver = chat.getReceiver();
                    if (sender == null || receiver == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(currentUser.getUid()) &&
                            chat.getSender().equals(userId) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userId) &&
                                    chat.getSender().equals(currentUser.getUid())){
                        theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                adapterChatlist.setLastMessageMap(userId, theLastMessage);
                adapterChatlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The code for ModelChatList is given below

```
public class ModelChatlist {
    String id;

    public ModelChatlist(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ModelChatlist() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I am trying to display the value of these child node in the Firebase but unable to do so because of the error.

Comment: This typically means that you're reading a single item from the database, but are expecting a list of items. What data do you have at `getReference("Chatlist").child(currentUser.getUid())` in the database? Please add it to your question as text (no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `datasnapshot.getValue(model class)`, you need to ensure that key and model parameter names are exactly the same. In your case, `ModelChatlist` has `String id;`. So your snapshot needs to have the key `id`.
Does `....getReference("Chatlist").child(currentUser.getUid());` return something like `id: "I am a string"` ? In effect, your data model parameters should be found as key values in the snapshot. You can still create your object with a subset of the keys from the snapshot but the names have to match exactly.